# MySQL select first 5 rows (multiple rows)

Tags: mysql

I need to select multiple rows in MySQL. I have procedure called 'proc_table' which returns me now 3 fields - oid, objet, and 1 row from db.cars. Query is limited (by me).

I need to delete that limit and make query which ll return me first 5 rows. If they don't exist there will be no reference (field with null value). I make some query in 'pseudo code'.

**Q: What function in MySQL I should use to select specific rows? How deal with situation if they don't exist?**

```
CREATE procedure `proc_table`() 
BEGIN
    SELECT a.oid as 'oid', 
    a.objet as 'objet', 


-- limited query
        (select tab2_oid from db.cars where tab1_oid = a.oid LIMIT 1)
-- limited query

    FROM db.tab1 as a;
END$$
```

## pseudo code

```
-- limited query
        (select tab2_oid as 'first_row' from db.cars where tab1_oid = a.oid where row=1)
        (select tab2_oid as 'second_row' from db.cars where tab1_oid = a.oid where row=2)
... 

-- limited query
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about using an union and a  LIMIT statement?

```
select feld1,feld2 from
( select feld1,feld2 from table1 where... LIMIT 1,1
union all
select feld1,feld2 from table2 where....LIMIT 2,1
....
)a LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I found something like LIMIT 1, 1 - which ll return me 2nd row - it looks quiet easier than union - what do you think?

Comment: my problem is that you don't use an order by so you have unsorted data and just want to catch any row. if you want to specify a row use an order by and a fitting where clause or if you just want to display any rows use the limit function (like 1,1) but with an order by without an order by you will display random data

Comment: if you need more help feel free to post comments here i will answer them when i have the time. perhaps post your structure to sqlfiddle.com so I can help easier